# SAS Data Mart files structure suggestions

Tags: sas, data-warehouse

I've been working on a SAS ETL project wherein we first extract data for the last month from teradata warehouse in the beginning of every month and then take it further for processing.

This is done via extraction scripts for each table and then the data is stored into a monthly folder structure (yyyymm). After working this way for several months, we've now begun getting requests to product daily, weekly, etc extracts.
The current data storage folder structure is :

Library/Data/YYYYMM folder in one library.

I have to change the structure(with minimal impact to the current structure)  to accommodate different timeframe requests like Daily, weekly, Fortnightly, Quarterly, etc.

I thought of two options : In the current structure (monthly folders), add in

- Daily, Weekly and Monthly Folders
- Library / YYYYMM / Monthly
- Library / YYYYMM / Daily
- Library / YYYYMM / Weekly

folders.

Option 2:
Under the Data Library Create folders like

- Monthly
- Daily
- Weekly
- fortnightly
- Quarterly

Under each of these exists individual folders with the current date/month/quarter.

Can anyone suggest of any other more practical design approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SAS generation data sets would be an option: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000934566.htm

Here an extract from SAS:

> A generation data set is an archived version of a SAS data set that is stored as part of a generation group. A generation data set is created each time the file is replaced. Each generation data set in a generation group has the same root member name, but each has a different version number. The most recent version of the generation data set is called the base version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zuluk, but this would be like complicating the current process even further. I want to add in a new file structure with minimum updates to the existing processes. Can you otherwise suggest any other option to add in periodic datasets?

Comment: No, however your first Option seems to me the best applicable one.